# count key in twig symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i try to simply count object into a city

[image: 1]

in paris, i have 5 object, i don't want show 11111 but just 5,

that my code

```
{% set newAnnounceCity = [] %}


        {% for item in announceCity %}


            {% if item.infoCity is not null %}


                {% if item.infoCity.city not in newAnnounceCity  %}


                    <span class=" font-semibold mr-2 text-left flex-auto">
                        <a href="{{path('app_city_show',{slug: item.infoCity.slug})}}">


                            <button class=" m-2 p-2 pl-5 pr-5 bg-transparent border-2 border-red-500 text-red-500 text-lg rounded-lg hover:bg-gradient-to-b hover:from-red-600 hover:to-pink-500 hover:text-gray-100 focus:border-4 focus:border-red-300">
                                {{ (item.infoCity.city) }}

                                {% for key in item.infoCity.announce|keys %}
                                    {{key|length }}
                                {% endfor %}

                                {% set newAnnounceCity = newAnnounceCity|merge([item.infoCity.city]) %}


                            </button>
                        </a>

                    </span>
                {% endif %}
                {% else %}

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
```

someone can help me

i try to count an keys object

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to guess without a sample structure of your input array, but maybe try replacing

```
{% for key in item.infoCity.announce|keys %}
    {{key|length }}
{% endfor %}
```

with simply

`{{ item.infoCity.announce|length }}`

Comment: yes thank friend, i have do it just after post message :)